# How can I quickly lookup an interface method's parameters from the Eclipse editor (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I am using Eclipse 3.5.2 for my Java projects.  Here is an example of what I'd like to do.  Given the class object I am creating for an Android project:

```
public class Test1 extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
```

I need to define 3 methods to satisfy the TextWatcher interface: beforeTextChanged(),  onTextChanged(), afterTextChanged().  I would like to be able to quickly look up the parameters for each method, after I've finished typing the method name.  For example, suppose I just added the line:

```
public void afterTextChanged()
```

I would like to be able to see the method declaration template so I can easily fill out the parameter list declaration for my implementation of that method.  I tried every option in the Content Assist menu that I could find and did not get any proposals.  Is there a way to do this?  I guess I'm looking for the functionality provided by the New Class dialog, but in a way that works with an existing class that I am extending to support a new interface, not a new class.

If there is a way to do this, then even better, is there a way to get the documentation's parameter list declaration pasted in without having to retype them myself?

-- roschler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Check this out: alt+shift+s -> override/implement methods

2) Also, somewhere in the class body press ctrl+space and select "afterTextChanged"

3) place your cursor in the first line of class declaration ("public class..."), press ctrl+1 and select "add unimplemented methods"

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the method name and just want to see its parameters, then press ctrl+space after you type the `(`

So, in your case type

> public void afterTextChanged(

and then ctrl+space.

You can also do ctrl+O to see all the methods for the current class. Press again ctrl+O  to see all methods from the current class and ancestors